# Raspberry power supply via PoE (power over ethernet)

Tags: power-supply, power, ethernet-port, alternative-power

Is it possible to supply a raspberry pi via PoE?

If not, why?

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs#powerPOE